# To show whether $\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \mid \frac{x_2}{x_1}=\sqrt{2} \right\}$ is a subspace of $V^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have problem understanding Linear algebra. So I searched for some problems solved of vector space on internet. Following the method, I tried to solve the above question too. Here is the process how I solved it.

Let us consider $u=(x_1^a,x_2^a,x_3^a)$ and $v=(x_1^b,x_2^b,x_3^b) \in V^3$.
As $\frac {x_2}{x_1}=\sqrt2$.

So, $\frac{x_2^a}{x_1^a}={\sqrt 2}$ $\rightarrow$  eqn1

$\frac{x_2^b}{x_1^b}={\sqrt 2}$$\rightarrow$   eqn2

To prove the given set is subspace of $V^3$, we need to satisfy two axioms(i.e addition and scalar multiplication)
1. addition
$u+v \in V^3 \forall u,v \in V^3$
$(x_1^a+x_1^b),(x_2^a+x_2^b),(x_3^a+x_3^b) \in V^3$
From the condition given above 
${...}:\frac {x_2^a+x_2^b}{x_1^a+x_1^b}$
Putting the value of eqn 1 and 2
${...}:\frac {\sqrt 2 x_1^a+\sqrt2 x_1^b}{x_1^a+x_1^b}
= {\sqrt 2} \in V^3$

Thus the given set is the subspace of $V^3$.

I did it this way but I have doubt with my process and answer as well. 
Please tell me where did I go wrong if I am and correct me.

Comment: You forget to write everything between $$.

Comment: Please fix your formatting so this becomes readable.

Comment: actually I have used mathematics symbols for the first time. no idea how to do it. :(

Comment: Just put every maths things between $$, i mean two dollar signs

Comment: Your "subspace" seems to be missing $(0,0,0)$. It would go better if you changed the condition to be $x_2=\sqrt 2 \cdot x_1$.

Comment: yeah in the addition operation I did it directly.

Comment: There are important information missing here:
(1) Which field do the scalars come from?
(2) Which set is $V^3$?
(3) How are vector addition and scalar multiplication on $V^3$ defined?

Comment: This is the only question given in my book. Now how do I show you the picture of the question?

Comment: If the description of this set is indeed as given in the book, then this can’t be a vector space since, as @HenningMakholm points out, it doesn’t include $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: This mean while satisfying the conditions my answer should be zero vector.

Comment: So as we need zero vector to prove it lies in $V^3$. I thought if we could try this way by modifying the condition. $\frac {x_2}{x_1}$ → $(x_2)-\sqrt2(x_1)$=0. While satifying both the axioms it gives zero vector. Won't it work?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that, in this case, the vector space is $\mathbf{R}^3$ and we're working over $\mathbf{R}$ with the usual operations of addition and scalar multiplication. We may recall the usual $3$ conditions that ought to be satisfied so that we can state that the given set is a subspace of $\mathbf{R}^3$:

1. Containing the zero vector.
2. Closure under addition.
3. Closure under scalar multiplication.

Your given set fails the first condition, since it doesn't contain the zero vector $(0,0,0)$, as $\tfrac00$ isn't even defined to begin with. However, if we were to consider the following set: $$\big\{(x,y,z)\,\left|\right.\, y=\sqrt{2}x\big\}.$$ Then in that case it would contain the zero vector, since $0=\sqrt{2}\cdot 0$, and it would satisfy the two other conditions for basically the same reasons that you outlined in your post.

Comment: Notice that condition $3$ implies condition $1$ (take the scalar $0$). Condition $1$ is a quick, good way to check if something is *not* a subspace.

Comment: You mentioned that if condition was y=$\sqrt 2$ x then it would have satisfied the other two condition. Then isn't $\frac{x_2}{x_1}$ same?

Comment: @Rima The problem only comes with the first condition, namely whether the set contains the zero vector.

Comment: @Rima The problem only comes when we consider the first condition, namely whether the set contains the zero vector. In this case, $(0,0,0)$ wont be in that set since $\tfrac00$ is not even defined.

Comment: Then it means any condition like $x_2$=$\sqrt2 x_1$ ,$2(x_1)-2(x_2)$=$x_3$ doesn't work??

Comment: @Rima Why wouldn't $x_2=\sqrt{2}x_1$ not be satisfied? We do have that $0=\sqrt{2}\cdot0$, hence the zero vector $(0,0,0)$ is in that set.

Comment: but you said that $(0,0,0)$ won't be in the set since $\frac0 0$ is undefined.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri The third condition implies the first iff the subset in question is assumed to  be nonempty. Otherwise, the second and third conditions wont be sufficient.

Comment: @Rima No, I said that $(0,0,0)$ wont be in this particular set: $$\left\{(x,y,z)\mid \tfrac yx=\sqrt{2}\right\},$$ since $\tfrac yx$ would be undefined for $(0,0,0)$, hence it wont be in that set. However, for this set $$\left\{(x,y,z)\mid y=\sqrt{2}x\right\},$$ $(0,0,0)$ is in it since $0=\sqrt{2}\cdot0$ and there's nothing undefined with it. Is it now clear?